# Can we use mysql and cassandra both in PrestoDB via connector?

Tags: mysql, cassandra-2.0, presto

In production system . I am using two different databases (cassandra and 
  mysql)

I heard about prestoDB and it is kind of amzing tool because we can make 
 sql query in Cassandra (Big database). Now come to analyze part I have 
 two different source mysql and cassandra i.e fetch data from sources and    query to different source. Is it possible to combine both in prestoDB.

PS : I am facing problem in mysql connector in presto. I have gone 
      through the documentation but it is not helping much

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and presto is the perfect choice for this kind of query.
First you need to configure cassandra connector and mysql connector.
Then you can combine data in cassandra and mysql in one sql like:

```
SELECT u.country, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM cassandra.tutorial.stream s
JOIN mysql.tutorial.user u
ON s.userid = u.userid
GROUP BY u.country
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Here is a tutorial of how to combine data in hive and mysql using presto, but combine data in cassandra and mysql should be similar.

http://getindata.com/blog/tutorials/tutorial-using-presto-to-combine-data-from-hive-and-mysql-in-one-sql-like-query/

Comment: I faced another problem of mysql db name and table with uppercase. Do you have any update of this issue: https://github.com/facebook/presto/issues/2863

Comment: Sorry but I don't know if anyone is working on this issue. Our mysql is case insensitive, so it's not a problem for us. I suggest you create a table with lowercase name and make a test.